# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSaslAuthenticator JavaMail Android

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send mail using JavaMail API in Android. My code is

```
Properties props=System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
session.setDebug(true);

Message message1 = new MimeMessage(MailsSharedData.getSession());
message1.setFrom(new InternetAddress(ConfigManager.getEmail()));
message1.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
message1.setSubject(subject);
message1.setSentDate(new Date());
message1.setText(message);
session.getTransport().connect("smtp.gmail.com",587,ConfigManager.getEmail(), Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN);
session.getTransport().sendMessage(message1,message1.getAllRecipients());
```

IMAP is working fine. In logs it show

> "DEBUG SMTP: Can't load SASL authenticator, THROW: "

Im using these libraries. I tried both versions **1.6.0** and **1.5.5**

```
compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.0'
compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described on the [JavaMail Android page](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android) and the [JavaMail OAuth2 page](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2), don't enable SASL.